# pytest: full cleanup between tests

Tags: python, pytest, freeze, fixtures

In a module, I have two tests:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture(request):
    prepare_stuff()
    yield 1
    clean_stuff()
    # time.sleep(10) # in doubt, I tried that, did not help

def test_1(myfixture):
    a = somecode()
    assert a==1

def test_2(myfixture):
    b = somecode()
    assert b==1
```

#### case 1

When these two tests are executed individually, all is ok, i.e. both

```sh
pytest ./test_module.py:test_1
```

and immediately after:

```sh
pytest ./test_module.py:test_2
```

run until completion and pass with success.

#### case 2

But:

```sh
pytest ./test_module.py -k "test_1 or test_2"
```

reports:

```
collected 2 items
test_module.py .
```

and hangs forever (after investigation: `test_1` completed successfully, but the second call to `prepare_stuff` hangs).

#### question

In my specific setup `prepare_stuff`, `clean_stuff` and `somecode` are quite evolved, i.e. they create and delete some shared memory segments, which when done wrong can results in some hanging. So some issue here is possible.

But my question is: are there things occurring between two calls of `pytest` (case 1) that do not occur between the call of `test_1` and `test_2` from the same "pytest process" (case 2), which could explain why "case 1" works ok while "case 2" hangs between `test_1` and `test_2` ?  If so, is there a way to "force" the same "cleanup" to occur between `test_1` and `test_2` for "case 2" ?

Note: I already tried to specify the scope of "myfixture" to "function", and also double checked that "clean_stuff" is called after "test_1", even in "case 2".

Comment: there's some bug / deadlock / global state pollution in your `prepare_stuff` / `clean_stuff` so this is unanswerable

Comment: Can you give us more detail as to what is happening in some_code()? That way we can answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely something is happening in your `prepare_stuff` and/or `clean_stuff` functions. When you run tests as:

`pytest ./test_module.py -k "test_1 or test_2"`

they are running in the same execution context, same process, etc. So, if, for example, `clean_stuff` doesn't do a proper clean up then execution of a next test can fail. When you run tests as:

```
pytest ./test_module.py:test_1
pytest ./test_module.py:test_2
```

they are running in different execution contexts, i.e. they start in an absolutely clean environment, and, unless you're modifying some external resources, you can easily remove `clean_stuff` in this case and they will pass anyway.

To rule out `pytest` issue just try to run:

```
    prepare_stuff()

    a = somecode()
    assert a==1

    clean_stuff()

    prepare_stuff()

    b = somecode()
    assert b==1

    clean_stuff()
```

I'm pretty sure you'll have the same problem, which would confirm that the issue is in your code, but not in the `pytest`.

Answer (score 1):

The current structure of `myfixture` guarantee `cleanup()` is called between `test_1` and `test_2`, unless `prepare_stuff()` is raising an unhandled exception. You will probably notice this, so the most likely issue is that `cleanup()` dosn't "clean" everything `prepare_stuff()` did, so `prepare_stuff()` can't setup something again.

As for your question, there is nothing `pytest` related that can cause the hang between the tests. You can force `cleanup()` to be called (even if an exception is being raised) by adding [finalizer](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#adding-finalizers-directly), it will be called after the teardown part

```
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture(request):
    request.addfinalizer(cleanup)
    prepare_stuff()
    yield 1
```

Answer (score -1):

It has to be something on `prepare_stuff`, `clean_stuff` or `somecode` because if you replace those methods by dummy code, it works!

```python3
def prepare_stuff():
    logging.warning("prepare_stuff()")

def clean_stuff():
    logging.warning("clean_stuff()")

def somecode():
    logging.warning("somecode()")
    return 0
```

```
/tmp/tmp.JOfTxVUv1z via  v3.8.10 (.env) 
❯ pytest ./test_module.py -k "test_1 or test_2"
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /tmp/tmp.JOfTxVUv1z
collected 2 items                                                              

test_module.py FF                                                        [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________________ test_1 ____________________________________

myfixture = 1

    def test_1(myfixture):
        a = somecode()
>       assert a==1
E       assert 0 == 1

test_module.py:25: AssertionError
------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------
WARNING  root:test_module.py:5 prepare_stuff()
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
WARNING  root:test_module.py:13 somecode()
---------------------------- Captured log teardown -----------------------------
WARNING  root:test_module.py:9 clean_stuff()
____________________________________ test_2 ____________________________________

myfixture = 1

    def test_2(myfixture):
        b = somecode()
>       assert b==1
E       assert 0 == 1

test_module.py:29: AssertionError
------------------------------ Captured log setup ------------------------------
WARNING  root:test_module.py:5 prepare_stuff()
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
WARNING  root:test_module.py:13 somecode()
---------------------------- Captured log teardown -----------------------------
WARNING  root:test_module.py:9 clean_stuff()
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_module.py::test_1 - assert 0 == 1
FAILED test_module.py::test_2 - assert 0 == 1
============================== 2 failed in 0.03s ===============================

/tmp/tmp.JOfTxVUv1z via  v3.8.10 (.env)
```